# Base64 & JSON Encode array in PHP, use as HTML data attribute, decode and parse in JavaScript .... with proper Escaping

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I'm looking to pass an arbitrary array from PHP to JavaScript while properly escaping. I'm leaning on using base64 and I imagine that base64 isn't data attribute safe, so as a good developer I am esc_attr the data. Is there a `right` way to make sure that the base64 data maintains its integrity in JavaScript?

Here's a contrived example -- that works fine -- because the esc_attr does not modify the integrity of the base64 encoding.

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'the' => 'quick',
        'brown'  => 'fox'
    ],
    [
        'test' => 'test',
        'foo'  => 'bar'
    ]
];
$values_json = base64_encode( json_encode( $array ) );
?>

<input id="check" type="checkbox" data-value="<?php esc_attr_e( $values_json ); ?>"> Foobar

<script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    checkbox.addEventListener('click',
        function () {
            console.log(JSON.parse(atob(this.dataset.value)));
        }
    );
</script>
```

In my research I came across [this solution for handling this using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838593/is-it-bad-to-add-json-on-html-data-attribute) - however the way I am getting the data I don't have an easy way to key the data to retrieve it by using the key as a data attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible output of `base64_encode()` contains `a-zA-Z0-9+/` and possibly `=` or `==` appended.

Testing with

```
$str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+/=';
```

we find that:

```
esc_attr( $str ) === $str
```

is true, so it looks like `esc_attr()` preserves base64 encoded strings.

There are [possible regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/475217/2078474) to help with validation, but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3500400/2078474) by @BoltClock, we could check it with the second *strict* parameter of:

```
base64_decode( $str, $strict = true )
```

We could then wrap it in a function like:

```
function is_base64( $str )
{
    return base64_decode( $str, true) !== false;
}
```

to validate it in PHP.